# Get host name of requesting server

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets

Say I have 2 different websites.

1. sampledomain1.com (Contains resource to be fetched)
2. sampledomain2.com (Implements Apache HttpClient to make a Get request for fetching resource from **sampledomain1.com**

I need to make sure that `sampledomain1.com` provides information only to `sampledomain2.com` and no one else. For this `sampledomain1.com` needs to find out what is the host name of requesting server. This mean, `sampledomain1.com` should read that request comes from `sampledomain2.com`

How can we find out?

Answer (score 1):

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

    if(req.getRemoteHost().endsWith("sampledomain1.com") || req.getRemoteHost().endsWith("sampledomain2.com")) {
        // ... code goes here.
    }
}
```

You can use `HttpServletRequest.getRemoteAddr()` or `HttpServletRequest.getRemoteHost()` to retrieve caller details. Perhaps you should use either a firewall or valves (http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/valve.html#Remote_Host_Filter) (or an Apache HTTPd server in front of your application server) to perform filtering, but this depends on your environment.

Comment: Could you please elaborate what do you mean by firewall or valves. I am using nginx.

Comment: Put (use) a firewall in front of your service which allows only packet from the allowed source. You can do this also with nginx (http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_access_module.html) by specifying IP adresses/ranges. If you use Tomcat for application server, you can add filters (see link) to allow/deny particular hosts.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$allowed_hosts = array('foo.example.com', 'bar.example.com');
if (!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) || !in_array($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], $allowed_hosts)) {
    header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].' 400 Bad Request');
    exit;
```

Comment: The question is Java-related, not PHP